# mysql will not start from cron job

Tags: mysql, cron, ubuntu-10.04

/etc/init.d/mysql start
works when executing through shell command
works when put in a bash script, and then executing the bash script
However when i try to execute this script from a cronjob
I get this error
/etc/init.d/mysql: 73: start: not found
Any explanations and how i could fix this.
I am on Ubuntu 10.0
oilChange.sh
`#!/bin/bash

service apache2 stop

sleep 1s

/etc/init.d/mysql stop

sleep 1s

/sbin/swapoff -a

sleep 1s

/sbin/swapon -a

sleep 1s

/etc/init.d/mysql start

sleep 1s

if [`pgrep mysql -c`-le "0" ]; then /etc/init.d/mysql start; fi

sleep 1s

service apache2 start

sleep 1s

if [`pgrep apache -c`-le "0" ]; then service apache2 start; fi

sleep 1s

cd /root/crt

php twatch3.php`

> This is what gets logged in /var/mail/root

```
    Subject: Cron <root@cloud> bash /root/crt/oilChange.sh
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ANSI_X3.4-1968  

    X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>  
    X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>  
    X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>  
    X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>  

 * Stopping web server apache2
 ... waiting    ...done.
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql stop

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the stop(8) utility, e.g. stop mysql
Rather than invoking init scripts through /etc/init.d, use the service(8)
utility, e.g. service mysql start

Since the script you are attempting to invoke has been converted to an
Upstart job, you may also use the start(8) utility, e.g. start mysql
/etc/init.d/mysql: 73: start: not found
 * Starting web server apache2
   ...done.

root@cloud:~#

I have tried  
service mysql stop 
stop mysql 
Both work from cmd prompt, and
script execution from cmd prompt but
fail when the script is executed by the cron
```

Comment: Please show us the code and your shell environment.  My guess is that the path under cron is different from that ubder shell

Comment: @david thanks for looking into the script. I just posted it

Answer (score 1):

The [crontab man](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/crontab.html) page states that the PATH variable is set to a value that is guaranteed to find all the standard utilities.  Update and export the path variable to include all utilities.

Comment: service mysql start works from command line but cron does not work. service apache2 start in the script is working though

Comment: @sam: You'll have to find the differences between the two calls.  Without seeing all the code, I still suspect you have en error in your path.

Comment: @David Thanks for the comment David. I have pasted the script within the question OR is it something else I should be looking for?

Comment: @sam:  At this point I would put trace statements (set -x and/or set -v) in all scripts and identify the exact line that is throwing the error.  This may give a hit why you are getting this error.

Comment: @David Thanks again, I just pasted what gets logged in the /var/mail/root by the cron job.

Comment: @sam: From what you've posted so far,, I still suspect issues with the path under cron.  To identify the cause, I'd add the command 'which start' to all scripts and use the output from these additions to identify why the cron jobs fail.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because it is not a script, it's a script with an added paramter. You might need `"` or something like that.